# Регулярные выражения в javascript

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Здравствуйте
Есть строка:

```
<p class="MsoBodyText" style="margin-right:-.1pt;text-indent:36.0pt;line-height:
```

150%;page-break-after:avoid">Some text</p>

Нужно удалить атрибуты class и style, чтобы в конце было так:

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

Это строка, а не элемент DOM
Спасибо.

Comment: почему бы не сделать из нее элемент DOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуется мне что вот так

```
myString.replace(/<p[^>]*>(.*)<\/p>/, '<p>$1</p>');
```

Comment: **(.\*?)**